# Air data rate nRF24L01

Tags: arduino-uno, nrf24l01+

I'm using two [nRF24L01](http://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/2.4GHz-RF/nRF24L01) to communicate with each other. I did the right setup and they worked fine, however I wanted to change the air data rate to a lower value, for more stability, as the [datasheet](http://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/content/download/2730/34105/file/nRF24L01_Product_Specification_v2_0.pdf) says.

How can I setup the configuration for this?

After a small research I knew that you can change this using `RF_DR` 
to change the value of the transmission, but I didn't really know how I could exactly write the correct code for this.

Another question: does this effect the range of the module? Or does it only affect the stability? And if not, then which code can I use to extend the range of these two modules ?

Comment: Which library are you using?

Comment: i'm using this library https://github.com/TMRh20/RF24

Comment: The documentation tells you how to do it. Did you try reading before coming here? It took me precisely 15 seconds to find it from the link you just provided: http://tmrh20.github.io/RF24/classRF24.html#aeb9920e7a95699748b003c4a839b0814

Comment: can you please tell me where to find it, i'm sorry but i honestly tried to do my best, so if you can, give me where did you find it

Comment: Did you click the link I provided?

Comment: yes i found it, thanks alot  , so can you help me with my second part of the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38761/discussion-between-med-malik-and-majenko).

Answer (score 1):

Increasing stability will increase the (usable) range. At least a bit. You could try decreasing the packet size, to make it even more reliable. There is no way to increase the output-power (only decrease).

You could try different channels, and see which one gives you the best range in your application.

After that you have to get NRF24 modules, with external antennas and amplifiers.

Answer (score 1):

According the nRF datasheet if you decrease the data rate it will definitely affect your range.

A lower data rate will increase your stability due to which the nRF can detect weaker signals (-102 dB at 250Kbps) due to this you can significantly increase the range (up to 1km theoretically).

Also if you need to increase your range further you can attach an antenna with a higher gain than what you already have.

No other software changes will affect the range other than reducing the transmission speed.

Answer (score -1):

The documentation for the function you want is [here](http://tmrh20.github.io/RF24/classRF24.html#aeb9920e7a95699748b003c4a839b0814).

Reducing the speed doesn't directly increase the range, but increased stability will have the knock-on effect that the fringes of transmission distance will be more reliable, making it appear that you have slightly greater distance.

Comment: Your claim about speed and range is untrue.  A narrower bandwidth signal has a greater power spectral density for a given total power output, a properly designed receiver listening for a narrower signal sees less total noise, and depending on architecture may see higher gain.  The data sheet is even explicit about some of this: " The 1Mbps data rate gives 3dB better receiver sensitivity compared
to 2Mbps."  However it also mentions that transmitting the same data at a slower rate increases the period of time during which it could be interfered with.